# How to make a table like this in Latex?

Tags: tables

I am quite new to Latex and I would like to make a table like the following (possibly with more rows in the 'Series' column):

[image]

Can anyone help me with that? I tried to look it up online but the codes failed (I am using Rmarkdown but so far Latex codes have always worked).

This is the code I tried (and variations):

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{5cm} | m{1cm}| m{1cm} | } 
\hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text& cell2 & cell3 \\ 
\hline
cell1 dummy text dummy text dummy text & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
\hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? A simple `\begin{tabular}{llc}` should serve as a place to start from.

Comment: Looks like a 'normal' table you can simply make with the `\begin{tabular}` environment. Please provide a MWE that our help can be more specific.

Comment: Edited the post including the code I tried

Comment: The table you showed in your question is quite different from the code you added. (e.g. the amount of dummy text in the first and second column). Please be a bit more secific about what you want to achieve. Do you want to reproduce the screenshot with very little text in the first column and multiple lines with longer text in the second column or do you want to get a different table?

Comment: @leandriis I would like to have a table that is the same as the one in the screenshot

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ llr } 
\toprule
& Series & P squared\\
\midrule
& cell1 dummy text & 0.67 \\ 
& cell1 dummy text  & 0.67 \\
Factor 1 & cell1 dummy text & 0.67 \\
& cell1 dummy text & 0.67 \\
& cell1 dummy text & 0.67 \\
\midrule
& cell1 dummy text & 0.67 \\ 
& cell1 dummy text & 0.67 \\
Factor 2 & cell1 dummy text & 0.67 \\
& cell1 dummy text& 0.67 \\
& cell1 dummy text& 0.67 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 
\end{document}`  should serve as a place to start from.

Comment: If your table ends up being wider than the textwidth (overfull box warning), take a look at the `tabularx` package and use seomthing like `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXc}` instead.

Comment: @leandriis thanks a lot! super helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{llc} 
        \hline
        & Series & R-squared \\
        \hline
        & cell2 & cell3 \\
        & Industrial Turnover Index, Manufacturing & cell3 \\
        Factor 1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
        & cell2 & cell3 \\
        & cell2 & cell3 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular} 
\end{center}
```

Comment: thanks to you as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this, e.g.,  by having a `tabularx`-environment with two columns. The first column is the left-aligned factor-column.
The second column is the X-column.

That second column is to hold another `tabularx`-environment. That other `tabularx`'s first column is the Series-column and is an X-column. That other `tabularx`'s second column is the R-squared-column and is a centered-column whose width equals the width of the phrase "R-squared".

The width of the entire inner `tabularx`-environment should be `\hsize` as that denotes the width of the surrounding X-column.

In order to get the horizontal spacing right, you may wish to set `\tabcolsep` to zero-width and to use `@` for inserting horizontal space between columns according to your likings.

You may also wish to use some macros of the booktabs-package for drawing horizontal lines of different thicknesses.

This is how—after a first glimpse on the image provided in the question—I would probably approach the matter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newlength\tabcolsepcopy
\newcommand\Rsquzaredhsize{}
\newbox\tempbox

\begin{document}

\noindent\hrulefill Width of line of text \hrulefill

\bigskip

\begingroup
\tabcolsepcopy=\tabcolsep
\tabcolsep=0ex
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l@{\hspace{2\tabcolsepcopy}}X}
\toprule&%
{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}[c]{X@{\hspace{2\tabcolsepcopy}}c}%
  Series&R-squared%
  \setbox\tempbox\hbox{R-squared}%
  \xdef\Rsquzaredhsize{\the\wd\tempbox}%
  \end{tabularx}%
}%
\\
\midrule 
Factor 1%
&%
{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}[c]{X@{\hspace{2\tabcolsepcopy}}C{\Rsquzaredhsize}}%
  Producer Prices in Industry&0.67\\
  Harmonised Index of Consumer Prices&0.56\\
  Industrial Turnover Index, Manufacturing&0.53\\
  Compensation of Employees&0.59\\
  Gross Fixed Capital Formation Price Index&0.48%
  \end{tabularx}%
}%
\\
\midrule 
Factor 2%
&%
{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}[c]{X@{\hspace{2\tabcolsepcopy}}C{\Rsquzaredhsize}}%
  Cost of Borrowing for Households for House Purchase&0.49\\
  6-month Euribor&0.45\\
  1-year Euribor&0.45\\
  3-month Euribor&0.44\\
  Long-term Interest Rate Belgium&0.43%
  \end{tabularx}%
}%
\\
\midrule 
Factor 3%
&%
{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}[c]{X@{\hspace{2\tabcolsepcopy}}C{\Rsquzaredhsize}}%
  Government Spending Italy&0.61\\
  Unit Labour Cost Germany&0.61\\
  Government Spending Finland&0.61\\
  Unit Labour Cost Luxembourg&0.60\\
  Unit Labour Cost Italy&0.60%
  \end{tabularx}%
}%
\\
\midrule
Factor 4%
&%
{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}[c]{X@{\hspace{2\tabcolsepcopy}}C{\Rsquzaredhsize}}%
  Row 1 of factor 4&0.01\\
  Row 2 of factor 4&0.02\\
  Long long row 3 of factor 4 Long long row 3 of factor 4 Long long row 3 of factor 4
  Long long row 3 of factor 4 Long long row 3 of factor 4 Long long row 3 of factor 4
  Long long row 3 of factor 4 Long long row 3 of factor 4 Long long row 3 of factor 4
  Long long row 3 of factor 4 Long long row 3 of factor 4&0.03\\
  Row 4 of factor 4&0.04\\
  Row 5 of factor 4&0.05\\
  Row 6 of factor 4&0.06%
  \end{tabularx}%
}%
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't need linebreak-features and wish the table to be as narrow as possible, then use `tabular`-environments instead of `tabularx`-environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlength\tabcolsepcopy

\begin{document}

\noindent\hrulefill Width of line of text \hrulefill

\bigskip

\begingroup
\tabcolsepcopy=\tabcolsep
\tabcolsep=0ex
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{2\tabcolsepcopy}}l@{\hspace{2\tabcolsepcopy}}c}
\toprule&Series&R-squared
\\
\midrule 
Factor 1%
&%
\begin{tabular}[c]{l}%
Producer Prices in Industry\\
Harmonised Index of Consumer Prices\\
Industrial Turnover Index, Manufacturing\\
Compensation of Employees\\
Gross Fixed Capital Formation Price Index%
\end{tabular}%
&%
\begin{tabular}[c]{c}%
0.67\\
0.56\\
0.53\\
0.59\\
0.48%
\end{tabular}%
\\
\midrule
Factor 2%
&%
\begin{tabular}[c]{l}%
Cost of Borrowing for Households for House Purchase\\
6-month Euribor\\
1-year Euribor\\
3-month Euribor\\
Long-term Interest Rate Belgium%
\end{tabular}%
&%
\begin{tabular}[c]{c}%
0.49\\
0.45\\
0.45\\
0.44\\
0.43%
\end{tabular}%
\\
\midrule
Factor 3%
&%
\begin{tabular}[c]{l}%
Government Spending Italy\\
Unit Labour Cost Germany\\
Government Spending Finland\\
Unit Labour Cost Luxembourg\\
Unit Labour Cost Italy%
\end{tabular}%
&%
\begin{tabular}[c]{c}%
0.61\\
0.61\\
0.61\\
0.60\\
0.60%
\end{tabular}%
\\
\midrule
Factor 4%
&%
\begin{tabular}[c]{l}%
Row 1 of factor 4\\
Row 2 of factor 4\\
Row 3 of factor 4\\
Row 4 of factor 4\\
Row 5 of factor 4\\
Row 6 of factor 4%
\end{tabular}%
&%
\begin{tabular}[c]{c}%
0.01\\
0.02\\
0.03\\
0.04\\
0.05\\
0.06%
\end{tabular}%
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]